# Resize Polygon just by outer edge using OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am writing a program in openlayers2 of polygon resizing. So resizing function take two parameters 1.Scale and 2nd Origin. So my problem is I don't want to resize by taking origin. I want to change size by other methods, like By taking outer edge etc. So can someone guide any other method to resize polygon ?

```
function resizeFeatures(scale) {
        polygonFeature.geometry.resize(scale, origin);
        vectorLayer.redraw();
    }
```